# How to install command line tools on OSX Mavericks

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, osx-mavericks

I am running OSX Mavericks (10.9) and while trying to update a bundle in rails, I get the following error message:

> "You have to install development tools first."

I have Xcode already installed and there seems to be no option to install the tools from within the Xcode 4.6. How can I download and install command line tools via terminal?

Answer (score 88):

Incase, while trying to update a bundle, you get an error "You have to install development tools first." on OSX Mavericks (OSX 10.9), but you already have Xcode installed, you can still manually install the dev tools via terminal:

`xcode-select --install`

Do that and follow on-screen instructions. Your problem will be solved.

Comment: I just updated to Mavericks 10.9.1 a few days ago.  I was having trouble installing Phusion Passenger where a file was missing. I was advised to reinstall the command tools. I did this command and was able to successfully install it.

Comment: That works, but why did Apple want to remove that from Xcode Preferences->Download. Something to do with their innovative ideas?

Comment: If you *still* get the message, and mkmf.log indicates that gem is failing to find gcc-4.2, try `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2`

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691701/failed-to-install-command-line-tools-on-osx-mavericks?lq=1.

Answer (score 18):

I summarized the steps in this blog entry ["How to install command line tools on OSX Mavericks"](http://leviathan37.tumblr.com/post/76618063571/how-to-install-command-line-tools-on-osx-mavericks)

Installing command line tools in OSX 10.9 Mavericks changes slightly compared to previous versions of MAC OSX. Now you don’t need to install Xcode. You can install the Command Line Tools as stand alone.

1. Open Terminal
   [image]
2. Type “xcode-select --install” in terminal (without quotes)
   [image]
3. A pop-up windows will appears asking you about install tools
   [image]
4. choose install tools
   [image]
5. wait install to finish it will take 30 minutes
   [image]

I summarized the steps in this blog entry ["How to install command line tools on OSX Mavericks"](http://leviathan37.tumblr.com/post/76618063571/how-to-install-command-line-tools-on-osx-mavericks)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Seems like you summarised from [here](http://www.computersnyou.com/2025/2013/06/install-command-line-tools-in-osx-10-9-mavericks-how-to/) without acknowledging!!

Comment: Thanks you a lot. It's surprise to me that Mavericks broke all python dependencies and now I need to do a lot of work to prepare my Mac to work. :-(

Comment: +1 for explicitly explaining "Now you don't need to install Xcode. You can install the Command Line Tools as stand alone."

Comment: This doesn’t work anymore: “Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server.”

Comment: id it possible to do this without the GUI?

Comment: @Chet have you tried this one?
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107307/how-can-i-install-the-command-line-tools-completely-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 12):

open terminal 
and type 
`xcode-select --install`
or open finder navigate to

/System/Library/CoreServices

and open **Install Command Line Developer Tools.app**