# failed gem install rails on mac ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I downloaded xcode, command line tools, home brew, rvm, and ruby, but when I use the command `sudo gem install rails` I get an error message. Not sure what to do any help would be great, I want to install rails on my new mac.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/cheatermoves/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.14/test/test_atomic.rb
marshalls-MacBook-Air:~ cheatermoves$ sudo gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/cheatermoves/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/cheatermoves/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
    --with-atomic_reference-dir
    --without-atomic_reference-dir
    --with-atomic_reference-include
    --without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
    --with-atomic_reference-lib
    --without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/
/Users/cheatermoves/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/cheatermoves/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:519:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/cheatermoves/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:817:in `try_run'
    from extconf.rb:26:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What is output of `gcc --version`?

Comment: Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: I'm getting this same error...

Comment: The answer's in the output: you need to install dev tools. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216865/how-to-install-command-line-tools-on-osx-mavericks

Comment: @MarshallLanners Have you solved this problem? How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to be using sudo with RVM...  Try just:

```
gem install rails
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gcc --version
```

When you have done this accept user agreement from xcode! (this is what fixed it for me.)