# library not found for -lbundle1.o when installing python packages (ffnet, spacepy) on my mac

Tags: python, gfortran, osx-mavericks, anaconda

I have the anaconda python distribution installed on my mac (10.9). I'm trying to install the [ffnet](http://ffnet.sourceforge.net) package and the [SpacePy](http://spacepy.lanl.gov) package, but having trouble in doing so. Here is the error I get when doing sudo easy_install ffnet :

```
ld: library not found for -lbundle1.o
collect2: erreur: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
ld: library not found for -lbundle1.o
collect2: erreur: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
error: Setup script exited with error: Command "/usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -m64 -Wall -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/ffnet/fortran/_ffnetmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/src/fortran/ffnet.o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/ffnet/fortran/_ffnet-f2pywrappers.o -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/4.8.2 -lgfortran -o build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/ffnet/fortran/_ffnet.so" failed with exit status 1
/Users/nau/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py:252: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'numpy.distutils' not found while handling absolute import
  from numpy.distutils import log
```

I have the same "library not found for -lbundle1.o" error when trying to install the spacepy package.

I do have the following file on my mac :

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib/bundle1.o
```

I have tried to make a symbolic link :

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib/libbundle1.o -> bundle1.o
```

in case the -lbundle1.o was looking for libbundle1.o and not bundle1.o and have the same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reinstalled the developper tools using the command :

```
xcode-select --install
```

which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216865/how-to-install-command-line-tools-on-osx-mavericks)

I had Xcode installed before I updated mountain lion to mavericks, and I guess something went wrong or that it is well known that one has to reinstall the developer tools after upgrading to Mavericks.... Anyway that solve the problem.