# ld: library not found for -lbundle1.o even though xcode command line tools are installed

Tags: xcode, gfortran, macos-mojave

When installing a program using gfortran i get the error

```
ld: library not found for -lbundle1.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Searching stackoverflow i found [library not found for -lbundle1.o when installing python packages (ffnet, spacepy) on my mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868897/library-not-found-for-lbundle1-o-when-installing-python-packages-ffnet-spacep) , where the answer is to call

```
xcode-select --install
```

To install the xcode command line tools. This then gave me

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Telling me that i have already installed them. In case my installation was somehow corrupted i have already tried deleting /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools and reinstalling but it did not change anything. (My macOS version is 10.14.1, xcode-select version 2354)

Comment: The `-l` linker option specifies a library and that will be looking for a library called `libbundle1.a` or `libbundle1.dylib` so that `.o` on the end is spurious so it's pointing towards an invalid build configuration.  You need to provide much more information in order to solve this issue.

Comment: What information exactly do I need to provide? I know this installation works in principle, as i have tried it on both my office desktop (debian) and my home desktop (ubuntu).

Comment: Well more details about the package you were installing, however this is starting to sound more like a system admin question than a developer question.  Unless it relates to code you are developing then the question doesn't belong here.