# How to install Command Line Tools for Xcode 5.0.2 in OSX Mavericks?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, osx-mavericks

I need to install the Command Line Tools, in order to be able to compile Node C++ stuff.

#### [Using `xcode-select`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18216866/389745)

Trying to use

```
xcode-select --install
```

Yields

[image]

#### [Looking in Xcode's Preferences, Downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/389745)

Trying to access the Downloads panel in Xcode

```
Version 5.0.2 (5A3005)
```

Yields

[image]

<sub>*(no option to install Command Line Tools)*</sub>

How the hell do I install these tools? Installing them by hand didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

Two possible paths.

## 1)

Use the "Locations" pane in Xcode Preferences.  You're looking for something like this:

[image: Command Line Tools Path in Xcode]

## 2)

You can download the tools from [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/downloads), where it's sitting:

[image: Download the tools from Apple's website]

Interestingly enough, the description for the Command Line tools lists a *date*, but not a compatible Xcode version.  So the one I've opened up the disclosure triangle for is likely to be the one you want.