# How to install Jekyll on mac osx 10.9 with ruby 2.0.0?

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll

I am trying to install `Jekyll` on my mac. My mac version is `10.9` and ruby version is `2.0.0`. But when I used `sudo gem install jekyll` in my terminal, it went to mistake like this:

```
➜  ~  sudo gem install jekyll
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling porter.c
porter.c:359:27: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
      if (a > 1 || a == 1 && !cvc(z, z->k - 1)) z->k--;
                ~~ ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
porter.c:359:27: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
      if (a > 1 || a == 1 && !cvc(z, z->k - 1)) z->k--;
                          ^
                   (                          )
1 warning generated.
compiling porter_wrap.c
linking shared-object stemmer.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [stemmer.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/gem_make.out
```

I looked through here and tried many methods, but none of them work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you may have tried these already, but do you have [Xcode Command Line Tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216865/how-to-install-command-line-tools-on-osx-mavericks) installed? Also, have you tried `sudo gem update --system` like [this](http://shoogledesigns.com/blog/blog/2013/10/31/error-installing-jekyll-failed-build-gem-native-extension/)?

Comment: @nicksuch yes,I have tried all of these, but not working. I have fix the problem using rvm.

Comment: I would like to know how this could be fixed *without* resorting to use rvm. There must be a way, must there not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast-stemmer installation problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672677/fast-stemmer-installation-problems)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have ruby installed / managed via rvm.  I would definitely recommend rvm and homebrew on os x.  They will save you a lot of headache.

Here is a good link on how to set that up:

<strike>http://dean.io/setting-up-a-ruby-on-rails-development-environment-on-mavericks/</strike>
https://deanpcmad.com/blog/setting-up-a-ruby-on-rails-development-environment-on-mavericks

Comment: You are welcome, and thanks for the excellent post.  I've pointed plenty of folks there ;).

Answer (score 6):

it works with ruby-2.1.1
so you have to

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.1
```

and

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

P.S. if you don't have rvm - install it before :)

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB

\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Comment: I worked though the steps outlined in @DeanPerry excellent article and in the end your answer was the last missing part.

Answer (score 2):

You are using System ruby. Check out whether you have ruby install or not. For that you can use `which ruby` command and it will give some output likes

```
which ruby
/Users/amritdeepdhungana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
```

If you have not install it by following this [guide](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-a-mac--net-21664). Or you can install it from [rvm site](http://rvm.io/rvm/install).