# Problems with upgrading Jekyll

Tags: rubygems, jekyll

I want to upgrade Jekyll to 1.5.1 in order to get some of the latest features, but I'm running into some trouble.

My current version is 1.2.1 and `which jekyll` returns `/usr/bin/jekyll`. Rubygems is at `2.2.2`. I'm on OSX 10.9.2.

When I simply run `gem update jekyll` it tells me that there is nothing to update. When I run `gem uninstall jekyll` it returns nothing, even with `-V` on. `which jekyll` keeps pointing at `usr/bin/jekyll` and `gem install -v 1.5.1` then gives me compile errors, I guess because there is still an old copy of Jekyll installed.

The following is the output of `gem list`:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.0.0, 3.2.12)
actionpack (4.0.0, 3.2.12)
activeadmin (0.6.0)
activemodel (4.0.0, 3.2.12)
activerecord (4.0.0, 3.2.12)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activeresource (3.2.12)
activesupport (4.0.0, 3.2.12)
arbre (1.0.1)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (4.0.1, 3.0.2)
atomic (1.1.14)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
bourbon (3.1.8)
builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
CFPropertyList (2.2.0)
coffee-rails (4.0.1, 3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.3, 1.6.2)
commander (4.1.5)
country-select (1.1.1)
devise (2.2.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.0.2, 1.4.0)
faraday (0.8.7)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
fb-channel-file (0.0.2)
formtastic (2.2.1)
has_scope (0.5.1)
hashie (2.0.5)
highline (1.6.20)
hike (1.2.3)
httpauth (0.2.0)
httpclient (2.3.4.1)
i18n (0.6.5, 0.6.4)
inherited_resources (1.4.0)
jbuilder (1.5.2)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.0.4, 3.0.1, 2.3.0)
json (1.8.1, 1.8.0)
jwt (0.1.8)
kaminari (0.14.1)
kgio (2.8.1, 2.8.0)
libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
liquid (2.5.5)
mail (2.5.4, 2.4.4)
meta_search (1.1.3)
mime-types (1.25, 1.24, 1.23)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.8.2, 1.7.9, 1.7.7, 1.7.6)
multipart-post (1.2.0)
net-ssh (2.7.0)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
net-ssh-multi (1.2.0)
newrelic_rpm (3.6.8.168)
nokogiri (1.5.10, 1.5.6)
oauth2 (0.8.1)
omniauth (1.1.4)
omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
open4 (1.3.0)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
pg (0.17.0, 0.14.1)
polyamorous (0.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.0, 3.2.12)
rails_12factor (0.0.2)
rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
railties (4.0.0, 3.2.12)
raindrops (0.12.0, 0.11.0)
rake (10.1.0, 10.0.4)
rdoc (3.12.2)
responders (0.9.3)
rhc (1.15.6)
rubygems-update (2.2.2)
sass (3.2.12, 3.2.10, 3.2.9)
sass-rails (4.0.1, 3.2.6)
sdoc (0.3.20)
sitemap_generator (4.3.1)
sprockets (2.10.0, 2.2.2)
sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.8, 1.3.7)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.3)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15, 1.4.14)
turbolinks (1.3.0)
tzinfo (0.3.38, 0.3.37)
uglifier (2.3.0, 2.1.2, 2.1.1)
unicorn (4.6.3, 4.6.2)
warden (1.2.1)
```

This is the error I get when trying to run `sudo gem install jekyll` after deleting `/usr/bin/jekyll`:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile
make "DESTDIR=" clean
make "DESTDIR="
compiling porter.c
porter.c:359:27: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
      if (a > 1 || a == 1 && !cvc(z, z->k - 1)) z->k--;
                ~~ ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
porter.c:359:27: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
      if (a > 1 || a == 1 && !cvc(z, z->k - 1)) z->k--;
                          ^
                   (                          )
1 warning generated.
compiling porter_wrap.c
linking shared-object stemmer.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [stemmer.bundle] Error 1
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, still not working! Same error messages! :(

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. Now I receive the error message as described in my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the bug with the advice here; [Fast-stemmer installation problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672677/fast-stemmer-installation-problems)

Turns out I had to run `sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install jekyll` for it to work.

Have no idea what this all does though. :)